# The visualisation of a list of genes on URD object

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat

Seurat R package has some functions like **FeaturePlot**, **DimPlot** and **DoHeatmap** by which we can plot the expression of a list of genes on cell clusters. I am working with **URD** that likely does not have such options or I can not find that. URD has plotDot but would be clear only for a few number of genes (please look at the picture). Could somebody please help me in plotting the expression pattern of a list of genes in URD? As I am not good in R at all to write my own function or adopt Seurat functions to URD

[image]

For example Seurat DoHeatmap gives such a picture by which we can see these set of genes are being expressed on which group of cells

```
DoHeatmap(object ,genes.use=a vector of genes)
```

[image]

Or we can plot a set of genes on seurat feature lot to they are being expressed more on which cluster

```
FeaturePlot(object = pbmc_small, features.plot = 'PC1')
```

[image]

In URD only by

```
plotDot(object.6s.mnn, genes = a vector of genes, clustering="Infomap-60")
```

We can plot a set of genes but as you are being in the first picture that would not be clear much

My question is how I can plot a vector of genes on URD object

for example Seurat DimPlot function can visualise the expression pattern of a group of genes on cell clusters but when I am trying to do the same with URD, returns this error

```
> plotDim(axial.6somite, c("DDB_G0291149","DDB_G0291029"), plot.title="SHHA (Notochord marker)")
Error in names(data) <- cells.use : 
  invalid to use names()<- on an S4 object of class 'dgCMatrix'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (label.type == "meta" | (label.type == "search" & label %in%  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (label.type == "group" | (label.type == "search" & label %in%  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (label.type == "sig" | (label.type == "search" & label %in%  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (label.type == "gene" | (label.type == "search" & label %in%  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> 
>
```

Actually only one gene can be visualised by this function on URD

Comment: Which plot do you want? Could you post an example from the similar function from Seurat? You say you are not good at R, did you try learning with a bootcamp or with online books (such as [this one](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use on our machines to reproduce your code. Those users who can answer will need to have access to a test dataset they can use to test their answers. Not your entire data, just a small part of it, or a similar dataset that we can play with.

Comment: Sorry, I know something in R but not as good as to be able write a function in a deadline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added URD clustering labels for each cel to seurat object and then I did DoHeatmap by using group.by="URD clustering labels"